# OutOfMemoryException reading from storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone, storage

I am just playing with Windows Phone developing and using the storage.

On the storage, I have a 10MB file with NUL in it. Now, I want to test how long it takes to read this file from storage.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    before = DateTime.Now;
    input = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(resultfile);
    after = DateTime.Now;
}
```

It's just a snippet, but this gets me the following error:

> System.OutOfMemoryException" in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   WinRT-Informationen: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

It occurs when `i == 4`. If the file to read is only 1MB, the error never occurs.

Can somebody explain me what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I call input.clear() or GC.collect() it works!